# VPN for static e-mail delivery IP?

Tags: postfix, vpn

As we all know, e-mail from a server with a dynamic IP-Adress is (nearly) always rejected because of the high risk of spam.

Now I had the following idea and wanted to ask you if this'll work.

- Let your (actual) server be connected to a dynamic IP router
- Let the MX record point to this dynamic IP (for receiving)
- Now let's further assume one buys an VPN access with a dedicated static IP
- Finally relay the whole traffic (ingoing and/or outgoing?) of the postfix email server through this VPN

Will this setup by "resistant" against rejections of dynamic range IPs?

Note: Actual static IPs aren't an option.

Comment: ...or you can use a [Smarthost service](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=smarthost+service&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could work provided:

- The VPN connection is permanent and reliable
- The MX record actually points to the static address
- Outgoing mail is sent though the VPN
- Incoming messages are received on port 25 (or other) on the static IP and are tunneled to your machine via the VPN

If your VPN connection is intermittent, I suggest you go for a VPS.

Comment: Why is it necessary, that incoming mail is routed via the VPN?

Comment: Because of the nature of DNS. You cannot have a reliable mail system on a changing IP. It might work at times, but you'd be loosing emails. OTOH a VPS will store those incoming e-mails for you, provide a VPN as well (as long as you have a proper VPS), and will cost just a trifle more.